# Операция сдвига вправо

Tags: c++, битовые-операции

В этом коде ниже `res` будет равно `-2`.

```
int main()
{   
    int res = -28299 >> 14;
}
```

В этом коде ниже `res` будет равно `1`. Почему?

```
int main()
{   
    int res = 28299 >> 14;
}
```

Comment: А вы представляете, как в бинарном виде выглядят эти числа (отрицательные в дополнительном коде)?

Comment: Можно и попроще числа взять, +3 и -3, и сдвинуть на 1 вправо в виндовом калькуляторе в

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Возьмём для упрощения 16-битный `int`. Упомянутые числа в битовом представлении будут выглядеть следующим образом:

| десятичный вид | двоичный вид |
| --- | --- |
| -28299 | ``` 1001'0001'0111'0101 ``` |
| +28299 | ``` 0110'1110'1000'1011 ``` |

Оператор `>>` обеспечивает в данном случае арифметический сдвиг вправо на указанное кол-во разрядов. Это значит, что знаковый бит будет повторяться при сдвиге (для отрицательного числа `1`, для положительного `0`) и использоваться в качестве заполнителя на пустом месте. Получится такой результат (жирным выделены биты, которые "остались" от исходного числа после сдвига):

| десятичный вид | двоичный вид |
| --- | --- |
| -28299 >> 14 | ``` 1111'1111'1111'1110 ``` |
| +28299 >> 14 | ``` 0000'0000'0000'0001 ``` |

Учитывая способ представления отрицательных чисел в виде [дополнительного кода](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%94%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4), получим `-2` и `+1` соответственно.